# Overlying Divs with position absolute

Tags: css, css-position, padding, absolute

I have placed one `<div>` over another one with position absolute and with 10px padding to the left margin (this is because I want to show a shadow). 
The problem is that the content of the base `<div>` is showed on the left of the header `<div>`, how to avoid this? If I use border-left instead of padding-left the shadow is not showed.

```css
#container {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.bigContent{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.scroll{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.header{
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-left:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.headerContent{
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">
    <div class="headerContent">
      <div class="shadow">
        <table width="500px">
          <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="item scroll">
      <div class="bigContent">
         <table width="500px">
            <tr><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add  .header {background-color: white);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the content of the base `<div>` is showed on the
>   left of the header `<div>`, how to avoid this?

You have correctly added `padding-left` on the header div to allow for the shadow, and the header div is indeed on top of the content. However, the header div has a *transparent* background by default.

So in order to hide the content below - you could simply add a white background to the header div.

```
.header {
  ...
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.bigContent{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.scroll{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.header{
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-left:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.headerContent{
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">
    <div class="headerContent">
      <div class="shadow">
        <table width="500px">
          <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="item scroll">
      <div class="bigContent">
         <table width="500px">
            <tr><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this solves the problem very quickly, imo it is better to get rid of the covering div element and use pseudo elements instead.

Comment: That depends what the OP needs the overlay for. What if he has links inside? I'm assuming the OP posted a simplified version of what he needs